# How to change name of a kubernetes node

Tags: kubernetes

I have a running node in a kubernetes cluster.  Is there a way I can change its name?

I have tried to

1. delete the node using kubectl delete
2. change the name in the node's manifest
3. add the node back.

But the node won't start.

Anyone know how it should be done?

Thanks

Comment: which k8s version? how many masters/workers you have?

Comment: Both client and server version are:  Major:"1", Minor:"6".  I have 1 master and 2 workers

Comment: There is a command to do it: `hostnamectl`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usualy it's kubelet that is responsible for registering the node under particular name, so you should make changes to your nodes kubelet configuration and then it should pop up as new node.

Comment: Can you tell me more where I can find the kubelet configuration file?

Comment: that really depends on how you provisioned your cluster, but it's likely to be in a systemd unit file, potentialy in /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service. You want to look for `--hostname-override` flag

Comment: did you try to do that on a master node with as a result a rename and did the cluster work afterwards as it should ?

Answer (score 10):

Changing the node's name is not possible at the moment, it requires you to remove and rejoin the node.
You need to make sure the hostname is changed to the new name, remove the node, reset it and rejoin it.

(you will notice that with the command : kubectl edit node  , you will get an error if you try and save the name:
A copy of your changes has been stored to "/tmp/kubectl-edit-qlh54.yaml"
error: At least one of apiVersion, kind and name was changed
)

Ideally you have removed the running pods on it.
You can try to run `kubectl drain <node_name_to_rename>` . Proceed at your own risk if that doesn't complete . --ignore-daemon-sets can be used to ignore possible issues for pods that cannot be evicted.

In short, for a node that has been renamed and is out of the cluster on CentOS 7:

```
kubectl delete node <original-nodename>
```

Then on the node that you want to rejoin, as root:

```
kubeadm reset
```

check the output and see if it applies to your setup (for potential further cleanup).

Now generate the join command on the master node:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf #(or wherever you have it)
kubeadm token create --print-join-command
```

Run the output on the worker node you have just reset:

```
kubeadm join <masternode_ip_address>:6443 --token somegeneratedtoken --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:somesha256hashthatyougotfromtheabovecommand
```

If you run `kubectl get nodes` it should show up now with the new name

output in my case:

```
W0220 10:43:23.286109   11473 join.go:346] [preflight] WARNING: JoinControlPane.controlPlane settings will be ignored when control-plane flag is not set.
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[kubelet-start] Downloading configuration for the kubelet from the "kubelet-config-1.17" ConfigMap in the kube-system namespace
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[kubelet-start] Waiting for the kubelet to perform the TLS Bootstrap...

This node has joined the cluster:
* Certificate signing request was sent to apiserver and a response was received.
* The Kubelet was informed of the new secure connection details.

Run 'kubectl get nodes' on the control-plane to see this node join the cluster.
```

Enjoy your renamed node!

Based on source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqoA9HwFLVU

Comment: This got me most of the way there, the thing that was missing was setting the "--node-name string" argument, which kubeadm will automatically use to override the hostname. See more at https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-join/

Comment: I did not need that, I am not sure what you mean with override in this context. Perhaps DNS is not setup properly on either node? I think the name is the same as the command 'hostname' output by default. But perhaps I missed something, thanks for the addition, it may help others.