# Kubelet could not register to master after the hostname changed

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

The following error was encountered within `kubelet` service when I changed the hostname of one of the nodes:

```
Aug 24 14:28:32 k8s-worker03 kubelet[9255]: E0824 14:28:32.715201    9255 kubelet_node_status.go:103] Unable to register node "k8s-worker03" with API server: nodes "k8s-worker03" is forbidden: node "localhost.localdomain" cannot modify node "k8s-worker03
```

It was firstly localhost.localdomain and joined the cluster successfully. After the hostname was changed, it was not ready within the output of `kubectl get nodes`

I tried to delete the node from cluster, and restart the kubelet service on that particular node, but this error appears again with the node not being able to register to the cluster.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change name of a kubernetes node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006716/how-to-change-name-of-a-kubernetes-node)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it seems while registering the node, kubelet is sending the hostname as "k8s-worker03" to API server and which is mismatching with etcd database records for your node as you initiated the cluster with node's hostname as "localhost.localdomain".
so suitable workaround here is to add flag --hostname-override <hostname_or_ip> as argument to $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS in your kubeadm.conf file.

Location of kubeadm.conf file can be found by checking the status of kubelet
for me the location was /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf

And the line to update is:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS $KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS $KUBELET_DNS_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS **--hostname-override=k8s-worker03**

then perform daemon reload and kubelet restart.

And if this doesnt work you have to

1. delete the node
2. kubeadm reset on that node
3. update kubeadm.conf file with the --hostname-override=k8s-master03 flag
4. kubeadm join/init
5. daemon reoload and kubelet restart