# kubernetes master node is NOTReady | Unable to register node "node-server", it is forbidden

Tags: kubernetes

I've been trying to troubleshoot my kubernetes cluster since my master node is NOT Ready. I've followed guides on StackOverflow and Kubernetes troubleshooting guide but I am not able to pinpoint the issue. I'm relatively new to kubernetes.

Here's what I have tried:

```
#kubectl get nodes
NAME                              STATUS     ROLES    AGE    VERSION
NodeName                          NotReady   master   213d   v1.16.2


#kubectl describe node NodeName
  Conditions:
  Type                 Status    LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason              Message
  ----                 ------    -----------------                 ------------------                ------              -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False     Tue, 12 Jan 2021 15:41:24 +0530   Tue, 12 Jan 2021 15:41:24 +0530   CalicoIsUp          Calico is running on this node
  MemoryPressure       Unknown   Fri, 15 Jan 2021 16:40:54 +0530   Fri, 15 Jan 2021 16:48:07 +0530   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  DiskPressure         Unknown   Fri, 15 Jan 2021 16:40:54 +0530   Fri, 15 Jan 2021 16:48:07 +0530   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  PIDPressure          Unknown   Fri, 15 Jan 2021 16:40:54 +0530   Fri, 15 Jan 2021 16:48:07 +0530   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  Ready                Unknown   Fri, 15 Jan 2021 16:40:54 +0530   Fri, 15 Jan 2021 16:48:07 +0530   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.


# sudo journalctl -u kubelet -n 100 --no-pager

Feb 26 12:23:03 devportal-test kubelet[11311]: E0226 12:23:03.581359   11311 kubelet.go:2267] node "devportal-test" not found
Feb 26 12:23:03 devportal-test kubelet[11311]: E0226 12:23:03.681814   11311 kubelet.go:2267] node "devportal-test" not found
Feb 26 12:23:03 devportal-test kubelet[11311]: E0226 12:23:03.782649   11311 kubelet.go:2267] node "devportal-test" not found
Feb 26 12:23:03 devportal-test kubelet[11311]: E0226 12:23:03.883846   11311 kubelet.go:2267] node "devportal-test" not found
Feb 26 12:23:03 devportal-test kubelet[11311]: I0226 12:23:03.912585   11311 kubelet_node_status.go:286] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Feb 26 12:23:03 devportal-test kubelet[11311]: I0226 12:23:03.918664   11311 kubelet_node_status.go:72] Attempting to register node devportal-test
Feb 26 12:23:03 devportal-test kubelet[11311]: E0226 12:23:03.926545   11311 kubelet_node_status.go:94] Unable to register node "devportal-test" with API server: nodes "devportal-test" is forbidden: node "NodeName" is not allowed to modify node "devportal-test"


Feb 26 12:23:05 devportal-test kubelet[11311]: E0226 12:23:05.893160   11311 kubelet.go:2267] node "devportal-test" not found
Feb 26 12:23:05 devportal-test kubelet[11311]: E0226 12:23:05.993770   11311 kubelet.go:2267] node "devportal-test" not found
Feb 26 12:23:06 devportal-test kubelet[11311]: E0226 12:23:06.095640   11311 kubelet.go:2267] node "devportal-test" not found
Feb 26 12:23:06 devportal-test kubelet[11311]: E0226 12:23:06.147085   11311 controller.go:135] failed to ensure node lease exists, will retry in 7s, error: leases.coordination.k8s.io "devportal-test" is forbidden: User "system:node:NodeName" cannot get resource "leases" in API group "coordination.k8s.io" in the namespace "kube-node-lease": can only access node lease with the same name as the requesting node



# kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                                      READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-6d85fdfbd8-dkxjx                  1/1     Terminating   8          213d
calico-kube-controllers-6d85fdfbd8-jsxjd                  0/1     Pending       0          28d
calico-node-v5w2w                                         1/1     Running       8          213d
coredns-5644d7b6d9-g8rnl                                  1/1     Terminating   16         213d
coredns-5644d7b6d9-vgzg2                                  0/1     Pending       0          28d
coredns-5644d7b6d9-z8dzw                                  1/1     Terminating   16         213d
coredns-5644d7b6d9-zmcjr                                  0/1     Pending       0          28d
etcd-NodeName                                             1/1     Running       34         213d
kube-apiserver-NodeName                                   1/1     Running       85         213d
kube-controller-manager-NodeName                          1/1     Running       790        213d
kube-proxy-gd5jx                                          1/1     Running       9          213d
kube-scheduler-NodeName                                   1/1     Running       800        213d
local-path-provisioner-56db8cbdb5-gqgqr                   1/1     Running       3          44d



# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.2", GitCommit:"c97fe5036ef3df2967d086711e6c0c405941e14b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T19:18:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.2", GitCommit:"c97fe5036ef3df2967d086711e6c0c405941e14b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T19:09:08Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: **Unable to register node "devportal-test" with API server: nodes "devportal-test" is forbidden: node "NodeName is not allowed to modify node "devportal-test"**

What happened here? Looks like the nodename does not fit to the current state of the etcd db

Comment: @ManuelPolacek Yes, they both differ. Can you guide me as to how I can correct it since it wasn't me who did these changes

Comment: I never did it before, but possibly this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006716/how-to-change-name-of-a-kubernetes-node

Comment: Did you try something already?